# Запись данных из консоли в файл

Tags: java

При записи данных из консоли в файл сбивается кодировка [image: 1]

```
package com.mycompany.praktika;
import static j2html.TagCreator.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    static Scanner sc = null;
    static String name = null, region = null, first = null, second = null, name2 = null, three=null,
                firstname=null, secondname=null, threename=null, add=null,add2=null;
    static String  ipn, scor, ipn2, scor2, prise, ipn3;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        sc =new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                 System.out.println("---ОДЕРЖУВАЧ---");
                 first = ("---ОДЕРЖУВАЧ---");

                 System.out.println("Найменування: ");
                 name = "Найменування: " + sc.next();

                 System.out.println("Регіон оплати: ");
                 region = "Регіон оплати: " + sc.next();

                 System.out.println("ІПН: ");
                 ipn = "ІПН: " + ifNotNumber(sc.next());

                 System.out.println("Номер рахунку: ");
                 scor = "Номер рахунку: " + ifNotNumber(sc.next());

                 System.out.println("---БАНК ОТРИМУВАЧА---");
                 second = "---БАНК ОТРИМУВАЧА---";

                 System.out.println("Найменування: ");
                 name2 = "Найменування: " + sc.next();

                 System.out.println("ІПН: ");
                 ipn2 = "ІПН: " + ifNotNumber(sc.next());

                 System.out.println("Номер рахунку: ");
                 scor2 = "Номер рахунку: " + ifNotNumber(sc.next());

                 System.out.println("Зняти з рахунку: ");
                 prise = "Зняти з раххунку: " + ifNotNumber(sc.next());

                 System.out.println("---ДЕТАЛІ ПЛАТЕЖУ---");
                 three = "---ДЕТАЛІ ПЛАТЕЖУ---";

                 System.out.println("ІПН організіції/отримача: ");
                 ipn3 = "ІПН організіції/отримача: " + ifNotNumber(sc.next());

                 System.out.println("Ім'я: ");
                 firstname = "Ім'я: " + sc.next();

                 System.out.println("Фамілія: ");
                 secondname = "Фамілія: " + sc.next();

                 System.out.println("По-батькові: ");
                 threename = "По-батькові:" + sc.next();

                 System.out.println("Адреса платника: ");
                 add = "Адреса платника: " + sc.next();

                 System.out.println("Телефон платника: ");
                 add2 = "Телефон платника: " + sc.next();

                 String fina = first + "\n" + name +"\n" +region + "\n"+ ipn+ "\n"+ scor +"\n"
                 + second + "\n" + name2 + "\n"+ipn2 + "\n" + scor2 + "\n" + prise + "\n" + three
                         + "\n" + ipn3 + "\n" +firstname + "\n" + secondname+"\n" + threename + "\n"
                          + add + "\n" + add2;

                  createDocx(html(
    head(
        meta().withCharset("UTF-8"),
        title("Чек")
    ),
    body(
            style("display: table-row-group;"),
            h5(first).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(name).attr("style =  \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(region).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(ipn).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(scor).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(second).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(name2).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(ipn2).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(scor2).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(prise).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(three).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(ipn3).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(firstname).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(secondname).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(threename).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(add).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;"),
            h5(add2).attr("style = \" display: table-row-group; \" ;")
        )
    ).render());        
    }


    static String ifNotNumber(String number){
        try{
            if (Double.parseDouble(number) >= 0) {}
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Введені не вірні данні: введіть знову");
            ifNotNumber(sc.next());
            return number;
        }
        return number;
    }
     public static void createDocx(String fina) throws IOException{
       // HtmlCreator ht = new HtmlCreator();
        //FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Chek.html", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("Chek.html"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
               // OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fs, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                writer.write(fina);
                writer.close();
       }   
}
```

Comment: точно ошибка кодировки при чтении с консоли? может она при формировании html? пройдитесь дебагом, посмотрите, что лежит в переменных после чтения с консоли

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getInput() {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        String path = reader.readLine();
        return path;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Как использовать: `String input = getInput();`

Чтобы записать что то в файл можешь использовать эту функцию.

```
public void writeToFile(String pathToFile, String text) {
        try{
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(pathToFile),"Cp1251"));
            out.write(text);
            out.newLine();
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Первый аргумент - путь к файлу, в который нужно что то записать.

Второй аргумент - сам текст который нужно записать.

Comment: зачем человеку метод записи в файл, если у него проблема с чтением данных с консоли? Вы только добавили обертку в виде BufferedWriter к его коду

Comment: Чем `FileWriter` не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

Важно в какой кодировке Вы читаете данные. Т.е. узнайте кодировку консоли в вашей операционной системе. Возможно ее надо будет переключить на другую. Либо при чтении данных учитывайте ее (что-то типа `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");`).